# String Formatting in Python/Thunderbird

Tags: python, string-formatting

Noob, trying to use Thunderbird (rather than SMTP) to send personalized emails to a few dozen people. I am basically looking to have the message display in Thunderbird as follows:

```
Dear Bob, 

It was nice to meet you the other day.
```

However, I instead end up with:

```
Dear Bob (comma missing, and rest of body missing)
```

I have tried the following:

```
import subprocess
import os

def send_email(name, email_address):
    #print(name, email_address)
    os.system("thunderbird -compose to= 'to',subject='subject',body='body'")
    tbirdPath = r'c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe'
    to = email_address
    subject = 'Test Subject LIne'
    #body = "Dear %s, \n\n This is the body." %(name)
    body = 'html><body>Dear %s, This is the body <br></body></html>'%(name) 
    composeCommand = 'format=html,to={},subject={},body={}'.format(to, subject, body)
    subprocess.Popen([tbirdPath, '-compose', composeCommand])
```

As always, simple answers I can implement are preferred to complex ones I cannot. I suspect I'm missing something stupid about string formatting, but am unsure as to exactly what. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Seems like you are on Windows. Try `\r\n`?

Comment: Yes, running Windows. No change with \r\n

Answer (score 0):

From [this example](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29), you may need to surround the arguments with single and double quotes.

Like this:

```py
composeCommand = '"format=html,to=\'{}\',subject=\'{}\',body=\'{}\'"'.format(to, subject, body)
```

By the way, if you are using python 3.6+, using f-strings makes str more readable:

```py
body = f'<html><body>Dear {name}, This is the body <br></body></html>' 
composeCommand = f'"format=html,to=\'{to}\',subject=\'{subject}\',body=\'{body}\'"'
```

Comment: I tried adding in both lines, no change, but thanks

Comment: It worked for me when the syntax was as follows:  composeCommand = "format=html,to={},subject={},body='{}'".format(to, subject, body)

Answer (score 0):

So here is a simple program to read in names and email addresses from a CSV file, and to automate drafting emails from your Thunderbird client (you will still need to hit send on each), using Python on a Windows machine.

```
import csv
import subprocess
import os

# a list that will contain OrderedDict ('Name', 'Bob'), ('email', bob@yahoo.com) 
each_persons_info = []

def load_email_info(data_file):
    """
    Load data from CSV files into memory.
    """
    # Load people
    with open(f"email_list.csv", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        # using DictReader, starts reading at row 2, with row 1 forming your labels, append to each_persons_info list (differs from csv reader in that respect)        
    for row in reader:
        each_persons_info.append(row)

def send_email(name, email_address):
    """
    Launches Thunderbird and drafts personalized emails to people on your list, using content you supply in subject and body fields below.
    """
    subject = 'Test Subject LIne'
    body = "Dear {}".format(name) +  '\n' + '\n'  + "This is the body." + '\n'  + '\n'  + "The End." + '\n'

    to = email_address
    os.system("thunderbird -compose to= 'to',subject='subject',body='body'")
    tbirdPath = r'c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe'
    composeCommand = "format=html,to={},subject={},body='{}'".format(to, subject, body) 
    subprocess.Popen([tbirdPath, '-compose', composeCommand])

def main():
    load_email_info("email_list.csv")

    # walk each person through the send email function 
    for item in each_persons_info:
        send_email(name, email_address)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```